# Functions on a group manifold

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Let functions $\varphi(g)$ map the elements of a group $G$ to some set ${\cal{L}}$ whose nature is unimportant (say, $\mathbb{C}^N$). The space of all these functions will be denoted with ${\cal{L}}^{G}\,$:
 $$
 {\cal{L}}^{G}~=~\left\{~\varphi~~~{\Large{|}}~~~\varphi\,:~G\,\longrightarrow\,{\cal{L}}\right\}
 $$
 Consider a subgroup $K<G$ and its representation $D(K)$ by linear operators on ${\cal{L}}^{G}\,$:
 $$
 D:\quad K~\longrightarrow~{\rm{GL}}({\cal{L}}^{G})~.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)
 $$
 For each fixed $k\in K$, we thus obtain a mapping
 $$
 D_k~:~~~{\cal{L}}^{G} ~\longrightarrow~ {\cal{L}}^{G}~~~,\quad
 \varphi~\longrightarrow~\varphi^{\,\prime}~~.
 $$
 In application to a group element $g$, this can be written down as
 $$
 [D_k \varphi](g) = \varphi^{\,\prime}(g)~~~
 $$
 or simply
 $$
 D_k \varphi(g) = \varphi^{\,\prime}(g)~~,\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)
 $$
 while in application to $\,g^{-1}\,$ this reads:
 $$
 D_k \varphi(g^{-1}) = \varphi^{\,\prime}(g^{-1})~~.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\quad (3)
 $$

QUESTION 1.

Without specifying a particular nature of the representation $D(K)$, is it possible to judge on some general grounds if $D^{-1}$ is similar to $D\,$? -- i.e., if there exits a transformation $F$ of the space, rendering $F^{\,-1}\,D_k\,F\,=\,D_{k^{\,-1}}\,$ for $\,\forall k\in K\,$?

QUESTION 2.

We can identify the group $G$ with its manifold, using some parameterisation 
 $$
 g~=~g(\alpha)\;\;,
 $$
 so expression (2) becomes some algebraic relation involving the functions $\,\varphi\,$, $\,\varphi^{\,\prime}\,$ and the coordinates
 $\,\alpha(k)\,$, $\,\alpha(g)\,$.

After we carry out the inversion of all the group elements ($\,g\,\longrightarrow\,g^{\,-1}\,$, $\,k\,\longrightarrow\,k^{\,-1}\,$, etc)
 will equation (2) turn into
 $$
 D_{k^{\,-1}} \varphi(-g) = \varphi^{\,\prime}(-g)~~?\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (4)
 $$
 ... and if yes, will that not be in contradiction to (3) ?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain your notation more clearly.  For example it's not clear what you mean by "linear operator on $\mathcal L^G$ when a priori $\mathcal L^G$ is not a vector space.

Comment: @D_S The space of functions ${\cal{L}}^G$ is a linear space.

Comment: How?  If $f_1, f_2$ are functions from $G$ to $\mathcal L$, what is meant by $f_1 + f_2$?

Comment: @D_S This is another function mapping $\,G\,$ to $\,\cal L\,$.

Comment: I know..how would it be defined though?  If $\mathcal L$ is just a set with no addition structure

Comment: @D_S Endow it with an addition structure then. This could be $\,\mathbb R\,$ or $\,\mathbb C\,$. It is not really important at this point. It will be enough to assume that $\,{\cal{L}}^G\,$ is a linear space .